# Segment lighter region outside a darker region

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, medical-imaging

I am doing a project in medical image segmentation.
[image]

For example, I have the segmentation mask for the darker region circled in red (already have a NN trained for its segmentation). I would like to segment the lighter region that's surrounding it (circled in green).
I prefer not to train a separate NN for that task and in best case scenario not to use DL models at all.
Training a new NN is not preferred as it would involve annotating many medical images and DL model is slightly less preferred because of inference speed but I am still ready to explore using pretrained models for segmentation.

Is they a way to leverage the fact that I have darker region segmented and that lighter region surrounds it?

Comment: Please post an attempt at solving this, currently, there's not even a raw image, hence also no MRE.

Comment: throw AI at it. you don't need that many images these days. there are models that, even starting dumb, appear to have good learning abilities, and there are pretrained models that you can fine-tune. -- don't look for shortcuts. "image processing" in principle will struggle and fail to solve the problem. anatomy is too complex for simple rules. if simple rules were able to solve this, everyone would be doing it and you would know.